# Factor in Gaussian filter

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conventions, turbulence

Why do Gaussian filter kernels commonly used in turbulence studies often have a factor of 6?
$$
G_{\ell}(|x|) = \left( \frac{6}{\pi \ell^2} \right)^{n/2} \exp \left( -\frac{6}{\ell^2} |x|^2 \right)
$$

Here are some examples:

1. [Pope, Turbulent Flows, p.563](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/turbulent-flows/C58EFF59AF9B81AE6CFAC9ED16486B3A#overview)
2. [Lee 1991, DOI: 10.1063/1.857956](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.857956)